# Elasticsearch store user input as JSON document

Tags: json, elasticsearch, architecture, spring-data-elasticsearch

I have a following architectural question - my application back-end is written at Java and client side at AngularJS. Right now I need to store the user input on the page in order to be able to share and bookmark my application urls and restore the state by this url.

I'm going to implement the following approach - every time the user interacts with my application via selecting the data and conditions at the page I'll collect all of his input at a complex JSON document and store this document at Elasticsearch. Key of this document from ES I'll send back to client application(AngularJS) and based on this key I'll update the page url. For example the original url looks like:

```
http://example.com/some-page
```

based on a key from server I'll update this url to following:

```
http://example.com/some-page/analysis/234532453455
```

where `234532453455` is a key of a document in ES.

Every time the users will try to access the following url - `http://example.com/some-page/analysis/234532453455` AngularJS application will try to get a saved state by key (234532453455) via Java backend REST endpoint.

Will it work ?

Also, I'm in doubt right now how to prevent the duplication of the documents in ES. Right now I have no experience with ES so don't know what approach from ES can be used out of the box for this purpose.

For example is it a good idea to calculate some hash code of each JSON document and store this hash code as a key of a document.. so before storing the new document I can check the old document by hash code. Also performance is very important to me so please take this into account also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For me it sounds you try to implement cache.

Yes you can do this but if you will use ES only for this solution then I think you should better look to [redis](https://redis.io/) or [memcached](https://memcached.org/).

I can't say that ES is bad solution for this but ES has some tricks which you must remember for instance its [near realtime search](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/near-real-time.html). After you index data they are not immediately available to search it takes few seconds depends on configuration(But you can also call [_refresh](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/near-real-time.html#refresh-api) but I am not sure about performance if you index data very often).

Hash: I dont see reasons to use has I'd better create right id. So if you have types of reports per user than id could be **"reporttype_{userid}"**, because if you will use hash as an ID then each new object will have new id and instead of rewriting you will end up with having many copies of old data for that user. if you go with pattern reporttype_{userid} then each time when user regenerate report with new data you will just override it.

As an option you could add to that option fields **userid** and **expireat** for future cleanup, for instance you could have job which will cleanup expired reports, but this is valid only if you go with ES, since in redis and memcached there is option to set expiration when you save data

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer. I was thinking about ES in order to avoid "technological zoo" .. because I'm also going to use ES as a search engine for my project. Taking into account  ES "near realtime search" feature I think Redis will be more appropriate place for such kind of cache..

Comment: Also, due to data and project nature I can't really to "report type" or "user id" as a data key. I'll user CRC32(calculated for JSON string) as a key of my document.

Comment: And the main criterion right now - I need extremely fast storage for set/get operations by own(provided by me) ID. I hope Redis should be a good choice for this purpose.

Comment: @alexanoid Then Redis would be best choise

Comment: I have one more criterion - the data in this cache should not be lost.. In other words -  the data should be persisted to disk and should be available after restart. Is Redis still a good choice for this ?

Comment: Redis should have option for that